# Authorization server behind kubernetes ingress?

Tags: oauth-2.0, kubernetes, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, kubernetes-ingress

I want to deploy a few `Spring Boot` microservices on `Kubernetes` cluster. One of them is *authorization server* serving `OAuth 2.0` tokens. With current deployment (no k8s) only two services are visible to the outer world: `api-gateway` (Zuul) and `authorization-server` (Spring OAuth). The rest is hidden behind the `api-gateway`. During `k8s` deployment Zuul proxy probably will be substituted by Kubernetes Ingress.

Now the questions:

- Should I put `authorization-server` behind the Ingress or not?
- What are pros and cons concerning these two solutions?
- What are *best practices*?
- Maybe I shouldn't get rid of Zuul at all?

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of Zuul is perfectly reasonable. Ingress should be the only outer-cluster accessible component that provides access to the cluster through ingress rules. 
So yes, authorization-server and microservices should be accessible through ingress.